# Unable to run GAE python project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-3.5

I am trying to install Google App Engine SDK for Python on my machine (Mac). Currently, I have Python3.5.1 running. But when, I ran the project on Google App Engine Launcher, I simply have this yellow "waiting" icon

[image]

I am unable to figure out what the problem is, infact, the log contains this:

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=14080 --admin_port=8006
Python command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

The only 3.X version GAE supports is 3.4 and only on the flexible environment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs

Answer (score 1):

[Google App Eengine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs) supports python 2.7 and 3.4 currently. Your python version is not compatible with GAE.

> App Engine’s environments, the standard environment and the flexible environment, support a host of programming languages. The latest versions of Python 3.4, Java 8, and Node.js are available in the flexible environment, PHP is available in the standard environment only, and Go is available in both.

Comment: Note that GAE only supports 3.4 in the Flexible environment.